# spark How to split in map and iterate each element

Tags: apache-spark

My input set look like below:

```
100,Jack,CEO,10000,IT
101,John,CEO,20000,CS
```

And I want to split each line and print all the columns using existing api in spark.

```
JavaRDD<Object> splitRdd = textFileRDD.map(x -> x.split(","));
```

How do I iterate and  print all the value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do this way:

```
 JavaRDD<String> p = textFileRDD.flatMap(x -> Arrays.asList(x.split(",")));  
p.foreach(x -> System.out.println(x));
```

This will print all colums.

Comment: Hmm...that will print each value on a separate line rather than keeping values from the same line together, but maybe that's what OP was looking for??

Comment: yup..but you answer is in scala i guess..am i correct?/

Comment: yes, you are correct :) But converting to Java should be trivial.

Answer (score 5):

So, if you are running in an actual distributed environment (a cluster with many machines), you need to call collect first and then call `println` on the collected results. Otherwise it will simply be printed to stdout on the different machines of the cluster and you won't see it on the driver. If you are only running locally, you could use `foreach` as everything would then be written to the same stdout.

In a Spark-shell on a cluster, I would do:

```
textFileRDD.map(line => line.split(",")).collect.foreach(array => println(array.mkString(",")))
```

which would output this:

```
100,Jack,CEO,10000,IT
101,John,CEO,20000,CS
```